# How to display complex class data in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

This is my complex class

```
namespace EnergaticWebApp.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
        public bool MyBoolean { get; set; }
        public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDateTime1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDateTime2 { get; set; }
        public List<string> MyStringList { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Person> MyDictionary { get; set; }
        public MyModel MyAnotherModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my action method in which I want to display my complex class data

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        var folderDetails = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $"wwwroot\ 
                            {"json\\my-model.json"}");
        var jsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(folderDetails);

        //  var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("my-model.json");
        var jsonModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsonString, options);
        var modelJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonModel, options); //not in use

        return View(jsonModel);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except when I am returning my jsonModel in view I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel]'

Any suggestions of how to do this?

Comment: Pls post your view too pls

Comment: Can you add content of my-model.json

Comment: There are too many ways to handle your issue. You can check my detailed answer. Wish it could help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear - you pass `MyModel` into the view (`jsonModel`); but the view expects `List<MyModel>` instead. They have to match!

Comment: when am converting into list:       var jsonModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyModel>>(jsonString, options);  its give me this error now: 
The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your model in the Privacy view

```
@model EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel
```

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
> ViewDataDictionary is of type 'EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel', but
> this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel]'

This error message means your view needs type of `List<MyModel>` but you pass type of `MyModel` in backend.

**The first way** is to change your view required model, but this way may cause you need change a lot for your html code:

```
@model EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel
```

**The second way** is to change your return model to `List<MyModel>`.You can create an instance for `List<MyModel>` and add your `jsonModel` to it:

```
var jsonModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsonString, options);
var data = new List<MyModel>();   //add this..
data.Add(jsonModel);
return View(data);
```

> when am converting into list: var jsonModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List>(jsonString, options); its give me this error now: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EnergaticWebApp.Models.MyModel]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1

Only your json like below can be deserialized to `List<MyModel>`. If you allow changing the json, you can use **the third way**(`var jsonModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyModel>>(jsonString, options);`)

```
[
  {
    "MyString": "sad",
    "MyInt": 1 
    //more properties...
  }
]
```